# run specific jobs on different runners - gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

[image]

In this image, i have 2 jobs, respectively deploy-job and deploy-job2.

deploy-job trigger master branch, and deploy-job2 trigger pico22 branch.

I have 2 gitlab runners. i want to run deploy-job2 on one specific runner which has tags: pico22, ttdocker. and another job runs on default runner.

It occurs wrong, what could i do?

I have tried to set variables, but it doesnt work at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "it occurs wrong"? What happens that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use tags to target runner/s which You'd like to run your job on.

CI Docs:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags